Why does hooking RtlDispatchException cause a BSOD
I want to fake CR3 for a specific process, so I hooked RtlDispatchException in kernel mode. I save the original DirTableBase from EPROCESS and change it to an incorrect value. This way, I can restore it in my HookedRtlDispatchException with STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION (0xC0000096)
However, I encountered a strange problem. It works fine for a while, but then I get a BSOD with error code `0xc0000096`. The address of the instruction that caused the bug check is:
nt!SwapContext+0x29c:
fffff802`10de139c 0f22d9 mov cr3, rcx
It seems that my exception handling function isn't being triggered this time?
Here is HookedRtlDispatchException
BOOLEAN HkRtlDispatchException(PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord, PCONTEXT Context)
{
    if (ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION)
    {
        if (*(PUSHORT)Context->Rip == 0x220F)
        {
            __writecr3(g_dir);
            Context->Rip += 3;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
 
    return OrigRtlDispatchException(ExceptionRecord, Context);
}

No need to consider PatchGuard; the BSOD is not caused by Pg.
